# Who killed Omi's dad?

Tags: plot-explanation, kai-po-che

Recently I saw [Kai Po Che](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2213054/) which is a movie based on the fiction novel '[Three Mistakes of my life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_3_Mistakes_of_My_Life)' by Chetan Bhagat.

In the movie, Omi's parents get killed when a fire breaks out in a train coach in which they were travelling. Two conflicting political parties were shown - one led by Omi's uncle and another by some Muslim guy.

My guess is that Omi's uncle got his parents killed by having the train set on fire in order to provoke Omi (who didn't seem interested in politics) against the other party which later escalates into a Hindu-Muslim riot near the end.

**Has it been explicitly stated (either in the film or any subsequent interviews) who it was that killed Omi's parents?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had read the book 6 years back but if my memory serves right there was no reference as to who set fire to the train nor was there any reference in the movie as well. Since the train burning is a direct reference to the [Godhra train burning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godhra_train_burning) that triggered the 2002 Gujarat communal riots, Neither the author Chetan Bhagat of 'Three Mistakes of my Life' nor the director of the movie 'Kai Po Che' would infer on who started the event as it is still a very sensitive issue.

But if you really have to get into the depth of the Godhra case you can check out the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yes, so that means the Muslim party set the fire in the movie at-least?

Comment: You can't be conclusive about it, but since 31 Muslims were convicted for the case in real and also considering the scenario that existed, I would assume the same as well.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that it was actually based on a real life case. This seems reasonably conclusive to me.

Comment: Richard the story is fictional but there are certain scenes in the movie which has direct reference to real life incidences. There are scenes which shows the earthquake in Gujarat in the early 2000, then the cricket series between India and Australia and finally the Godhra train burning incident and the Hindu Muslim communal riots.